# Problem with Intelligencia.UrlRewriter

Tags: asp.net, iis-6, url-rewriting, windows-server-2003

I am trying to use the Intelligencia.UrlRewriter tool that has already been used extensively on project I've inherited, where the application is deployed to II6.  I am trying to fix a bug in the application that occurs when trying to rewrite certain url's.

The following rewrite entry matches both web addresses ~/foo and ~/foo/ propery and rewrites the URL correctly:

```
<rewrite url="~/foo[/]?$" to="~/Default.aspx" />
```

but this rewrite entry only matches ~/bar/foo and not ~/bar/foo/ and when ~/bar/foo/ is entered I receive an ASP.NET server error page with the error: "Cannot use a leading .. to exit above the top directory.":

```
<rewrite url="~/bar/foo[/]*?$" to="~/Default.aspx" />
```

So, I am trying to get the second entry to properly rewrite the URL for the ~/bar/foo/ web address.

I am using ASP.NET v 2.0 and it is deployed to Windows Server 2003 using IIS v6.0.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

BTW: I have read ScottGu's blog entry about URL rewriting ([link](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/02/26/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net.aspx)) and was really hoping that I don't have to reimplement the functionality using an ISAPI filter because upgrading to IIS7 is most likely not happening anytime in the forceeable future and I'm a little time constrained.